# Hide the textview coming from UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have A and B `UIViewController`. A controller has button and textview and click this button it goes to B controller. Then I click the B controller I come back to A controller. But when I come back from B controller I need to hide textview from A controller.

B controller:

```
-(void)A{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Please explain the problem properly. You need to tell us what's going wrong, what you'd like to happen, and the steps you've taken to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using poptoviewcontroller method so after going back to previous controller the data still persists. So, before navigating to B controller from A controller hide the textview, so that when navigation view pops to main view, the textview will be hidden

Answer (score 1):

Try to use like this...
There are two solution

1.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    textview.hideen = NO;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   textview.hidden = YES;
}
```

2 . Use a key in `NSUserDefaults` for status . I mean check it is coming from B Controller or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options for this:

1. Before navigating to the next view hide the textview.
2. Hide the textview in the viewwilldisappear method.
3. Use a key with NSUserDefaults and check whether it is coming from B controller.
4. Declare a variable in appdelegate and change its value in B controller check the value in a controller hide the textview based on result.
5. You can navigate to another page by declaring a view controller and setting it to naviagation controller before that you can set the properties of that controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
->write code in controller A
```

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideTextview) name:@“hidetextview” object:nil];
```

}
- (void) hideTextview{

```
textview.hidden = YES;
```

}

```
->in controller B
```

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hidetextview" object:nil userInfo:nil];
}

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you could do is hide the text view in viewcontroller A before you navigate to view controller B so the code needs to be added in the

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
  textview.hidden = YES;
}
```

OR

```
- (void)navigateToBController{
   VCB *b = [[VCB alloc]init];
   [self.navigationController pushviewController:b];
   textview.hidden = YES;
}
```

If you are navigating from A -> B -> C and then in viewcontroller C you navigate to root view controller i.e A then in this case what i would suggest is to maintain a variable in [NSUSerDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which would inform you from which viewcontroller it has popped so that you could show / hide your textview.